# How to place coordinate with particular axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw this image: [image]

But there is a lot of things that I dont know how to do:

1. I've created my own axis, but how to define the coordonate now ?
2. How can i create the white, and gray rectangle?

Here is my MWE (with only the axis defined):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        %  width=\textwidth,
        % height=\axisdefaultheight,
        title={Débits moyen par taille de fichiers},
        xlabel={Taille des fichiers en [$Mb$]},
        ylabel={Débits en [$Mb/s$]},
        xmin=0, xmax=1010,
        ymin=0, ymax=30,
        xtick=data,
        xticklabels={<1 Mbps, 1Mbps, 10 Mbps, 100 Mbps,>1Gbs},
        ytick=data,
        yticklabels={1000 ms, 100 ms, 10 ms, 1ms},
        % legend pos=north west,
        legend style={at={(1.6,.6)},anchor=north}, % legend pos=outer north east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]
        \addplot[
        color=darkblue2,
        mark=circle,
        ]
        coordinates {(0,0)};
        \legend{Fixex}

        \addplot[
        color=darkblue,
        mark=circle,
        ]
        coordinates {(1,1)};
        \legend{Nomadic}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I know it's really from scratch.
THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has an interesting aspect, namely

> How can one revert the direction of a logarithmic axis.

I did not find an answer on this here, but of course I may have missed them. In any case, a possible answer is to use

```
y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{log10(1/#1)}},
y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{10^(-#1)}},
```

The rest is more or less standard. You can fill some area in gray using the `\fill` command, and if you want others to use your colors `darkblue` and `darkblue2` you need to provide them with the definitions. Also `\legend` adds the full legend, so you could use this command with a comma-separated list of entries, or `\addlegendentry`, which is more work to type but perhaps also more intuitive to use.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[xmode=log,axis on top,
        y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{log10(1/#1)}},
        y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{10^(-#1)}},
        title={D\'ebits moyen par taille de fichiers},
        xlabel={Taille des fichiers en [Mb]},
        ylabel={D\'ebits en [Mb/s]},
        xmin=0.5, xmax=5000,
        ymin=5000, ymax=0.5,
        xtick={1,10,100,1000},
        xticklabels={$<\SI{1}{MBps}$,\SI{1}{MBps},\SI{10}{MBps},\SI{100}{MBps},$>\SI{1}{GBps}$},
        ytick={1000,100,10,1},
        yticklabels={\si{1000\milli\second},\si{100\milli\second},\si{10\milli\second},\si{1\milli\second}},
        legend style={at={(1.6,.6)},anchor=north,row sep=10pt}, % legend pos=outer north east,
        ]
   \fill[gray!10] (0.5,0.5) -| (5000,5000) -| (500,5) -| cycle;     
   \addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=0.75em,
        color=blue!60!black]
        coordinates {(10,100) (100,10)};
   \addlegendentry{Fixex}

   \addplot[only marks,mark=*,mark size=0.75em,
        color=blue!80!black]
        coordinates {(20,30) (200,200)};
   \addlegendentry{Nomadic}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) (my bad to remove my special colors)